# Image padding problem with transparent

Tags: image-processing

I have an image that I'm trying to pad some transparent border. But I get error:

"The specified padding value is not compatible with a 3-channel image."

```
data = Table[{45, 45, 45}, {20}, {25}];
p = Image[RawArray["Byte", data], "Byte", Rule[ColorSpace, Automatic],
    Rule[Interleaving, True]];

ImagePad[p, 10, Transparent]
```

What does this error mean and how to solve it?

**Update**

If test on the documentation figure, padding transparent works even it has a Automatic color space:

[image]

Comment: Is there a reason, why you are using `Automatic` for the `ColorSpace`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to convert `Transparent` into, e.g., the RGB color space:

```
ImagePad[p, 10, ColorConvert[Transparent, "RGB"]]
```

This is due to the fact, that `Transparent` is `GrayLevel[0,0]` and is incompatible with the `ImageColorSpace` of your image `p` (`Automatic`, which means that no color space is specified).
You can also convert your image into a specific color space, e.g.

```
ImagePad[ColorConvert[p, "Grayscale"], 10, Transparent]
ImagePad[ColorConvert[p, "RGB"], 10, Transparent]
```

Comment: Thanks for the asnwer, it's very helpful. I didn't know that the problem was from color space. The`Automatic` comes from importing a video.

Comment: It' s strange that a figure in the documentation also has the color space goes to Automatic, but padding transparent works.See my update. Do you know why?

Comment: @xslittlegrass Its `Automatic` is different, as it has only one channel (use `ImageChannels@p` to check) compared to the 3 channels of your original `p`.